# Going beyond CRUD in RESTful services

Tags: web-services, wcf, rest, restful-architecture

I am working on a WCF RESTful service and noticed that on some places I can represent non-CRUD operations (not resources) in more than one way.

Say we purchased a new **TV** and connected it to our private network. Now we want to build a **Web Service** in order to view and control the TV.

- For reading and updating the TV's properties we will use the following URI:

  **http://domain/tv/**  GET | PUT - getting and updating tv properties. (`company`, `owner`, `inches`)
- For consuming video we will use the following URI:

  **ws://domain/tv/video** - (assume WebSocket is the best option for video content transfer)
- **And operations:**

  - `updateVersion`
  - `startBIT` (Built-in self-test)
  - `changeChannel`
  - `turnVolumeUp`, `turnVolumeDown`

First design is to use properties for representing operations. Server will notice property changes and then perform the desired operations. Finally **POST**ing the operations which can't be represented by properties:

> http://domain/tv/ GET | PUT - getting or setting `volume` or `channel` using a json objects.
>
> and for `updateVersion` or `startBIT`:
>
> http://domain/tv/ POST with {function: 'updateVersion'} or {function: 'startBIT'}

Second design is to represent all operations using a **Command** resource:

> http://domain/tv/commands POST with {command: 'BIT', sender: 'Dan' ... } - create new command for performing `startBIT`, `changeChannel` or `turnVolume`

Third design is to represent each operation which can be pronounced as a noun as a resource and the rest as properties:

> http://domain/tv/versionUpdates GET | PUT | DELETE | POST
>
> http://domain/tv/BITs GET | PUT | DELETE | POST
>
> http://domain/tv/ PUT ({volume: 10})
>
> http://domain/tv/ PUT ({channel: 29})

**What is the best RESTful design?**

Comment: Volume and channels can be resources as well ...

Comment: @David can I have one volume please? Not everything fits REST, RPC is one of those things.

Comment: Resources don't necessarily correspond to physical or concrete objects. Setting the volume: POST /blah/volume/100, changing a channel: PUT /blah/channel/13

Comment: @David what is `POST tv/volume/100` supposed to mean really, given the semantics of POST? `PUT tv/channel/13` might mean you want to update the frequency or description of channel 13, but not that the TV should switch to that channel. Why would you use two different verbs for setting the current state of two different things, both of which there can naturally only be one active at the same time - unless you got multiple tuners in the case of channels?

Comment: @DavidBrabant It doesn't look very RESTful because when referring to `blah/volume/100` it looks like we are using a a verb, the RESTful way is to use nouns. Your suggestion lookes very similar to `blah/changeChannelTo/23` ..

Comment: @Matan. Uh? Volume is a verb?

Comment: No it's not, but look what happens when I replace `volume` to `changeVolumeTo`, do you see what I mean? If we POST to `blah/changeVolumeTo/10` it means we have a bad design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third option (with the modifications mentioned below) seems to be the best designed - since REST is about resources and nouns, not about verbs and operations.

The changes I would apply:

- `http://domain/tv/firmware GET | DELETE | POST`

  I'd change `versionUpdates` to `firmware` - seems to be much more self descriptive. What's more it seems that `PUT` operation here doesn't make any sense - you probably do not know the new version of firmware a priori. So `GET` returns current firmware version, `DELETE` removes the latest and restores the previous, `POST` looks and installs for the latest one.
- `http://domain/tv/BITs GET | POST`

  Here it seems `GET` and `POST` will suffice. You just need to `GET` the results of all tests or of a particular one or just `POST` new test.
- `http://domain/tv/ PATCH ({volume: 10})` and `http://domain/tv/ PATCH ({channel: 29})`

  Since both are very similar - I'd change `PUT` to `PATCH` - remember that while using `PUT` you need to include the whole object - that is - every property. `PUT` is also idempotent operation. While using `PATCH` you can change just a single property.

Comment: What do you say about the second option (Commands)? When using `Commands` we encapsulates common TV operations (although it seems like it's a trick for treating all operations as a single noun, too generic..).. I agree with you about using as much nouns as we can (firmware and BITs)

Comment: I do consider command just as a wrapper for the operation. I think it's a bit awkward to treat function as a resource especially, that it will not be *kept* on the server side but invoked ;) Command might be useful for the remote control (if you need to model it) - however not as a function but rather resource. I do understand it's sometimes very difficult to model real world with REST, however we should stick to general rules as much as possible.

Comment: Yes, but how you can invoke a function in a RESTful way?

Comment: Yes, I realized that invoking functions need to be in a RESTful way, so PUTing new volume for example to `http://domain/tv/` is a much RESTfuler.